# How to Handle this Error in Javascript "net::ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When network is very busy on my PC, the Javascript (n Chrome) bump into net::ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED (or net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED) while making ajax call using Angularjs. 
 How do I handle this error?

Comment: Chrome which version that u r getting this error

Comment: @reena Version 41.0.2272.118 m